# Pass parameter to invoked action in before action Yii 1.1

Tags: yii, yii1.x

I want to make a simple control before some action inside my `beforeAction()`.

I initialize a model with the params inside the `beforeAction()`, then I want to pass this model as parameter to the specified action to avoid making this code repetition in every action concerned.

Answer (score 0):

first you can declare a variable in your controller for your model like

```
private $model;
```

Of course you can use any access modifiers according to your requirements. Now in your beforeAction you can initialise `$model` variable as below

```
protected function beforeAction($action)
{
    $this->model = new MyModel();
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Now you will be able to access initialised variable in any of your controller actions by `$this->model`. But if you want to initialise `$model` variable specific to any action then you can do it as below

```
protected function beforeAction($action)
{
    if($action->id == "index")
    {
        $this->model = new MyModel();
    } else {
        $this->model = new OtherModel();
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For those searching for this problem.
You can call $action->runWithParams.

```
protected function beforeAction($action)
{
    return parent::beforeAction($action->runWithParams(['param1' => $param1]));
}
```